# How to convert categorical index to normal index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame (result of the method `unstack`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(2, -1),
                  columns=pd.CategoricalIndex(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']))
```

`df` looks like this:

```
   a  b  c  a   b   c
0  0  1  2  3   4   5
1  6  7  8  9  10  11
```

When I try to `df.reset_index()` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category
```

To bypass this problem I want to convert the column's index from categorical to a normal one. What is the most straightforward way to do it? Maybe you have an idea of how to reset the index without index conversion. I have the following idea:

```
df.columns = list(df.columns)
```

Comment: Looks like you've already figured out the answer (your last line of code). Are you asking how to keep the categorical index when resetting? Or something else?

Comment: @cs95 I don't want to keep categorical index. It looks like I got it after `groupby` and `unstack`.

Comment: So you've answered the question. `df.columns = list(df.columns)` will work. Or if you want to get fancy, `df.columns = [*df]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most general is converting columns to list:

```
df.columns = df.columns.tolist()
```

Or if possible, convert them to strings:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)

   index  a  b  c  a   b   c
0      0  0  1  2  3   4   5
1      1  6  7  8  9  10  11
```

Comment: But they said they want to "convert it to a normal index", this answer seems to preserve the categorical index.

Comment: I would think twice about converting to string. If the categories were originally strings, that would be fine... but they could also be integer or bools, and we might want to preserve that information.

Comment: @cs95 - Yop, general solution is `list`

Comment: I am very new to pandas. I managed to convert a `CategoricalIndex` into an `Index` with  `df.index = df.index.tolist()`. I feel like the question title is not in sync with the accepted answer.

Comment: @Sydney - Here is it OK, because question need replace columns labels, not index labels.